# Injecting script with chrome.scripting in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to make chrome extension js code work with typescript:

```
    const [tab] = await chrome.tabs.query({ active: true, currentWindow: true });
    let result;
    try {
        [{ result }] = await chrome.scripting.executeScript({
            target: { tabId: tab.id },
            function: () => getSelection().toString(),
        });
    } catch (e) {
        return;
    }
    console.log('Selection: ' + result);
};
```

This logs user's selection on click of a button. However, when trying to work with this in typescript, it throws a cascade of errors at me.
The first one is `Property 'result' does not exist on type Property 'result' does not exist on type 'InjectionResult<unknown> | undefined'.`

I have tried fiddling around with ! and ? operators, sending executeScript to a different function via `func:` but have not been able to get this to a working state. I also tried to make result and ordinary variable, but in this case `No overload matches this call.` exception is thrown on line 6.
How do I go about resolving this? Also, can I find type reference for InjectionResult anywhere?

Comment: The code is correct. Use the official [chrome-types](https://www.npmjs.com/package/chrome-types) package. If it doesn't help then simply suppress the errors.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I am already using chrome-types, and still ts throws errors at me and I'm not sure why this is happening. Adding @ts-ignore lets package build and everything works as expected.